# Activate an excel sheet from VBA without knowing it's name?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to activate a sheet in an opened workbook through VBA without knowing it's name? I'm opening a workbook using `application.getfileopenname` and reading data from it, but some of the workbooks have the data on the second sheet, instead of the first. Is there anyway I could switch the active worksheet to the second sheet?

Comment: try yourWorkBook.Worksheets(2).Activate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wsData = Sheets(1)

'If the Range doesn't have the value you are looking for switch sheets
If wsData.Range("A1").Value <> "MyExpectedData" Then Set wsData = Sheets(2)
```